# Refresh a View Controller. Dynamic font size

Tags: swift, fonts, size, viewcontroller

I want to set up a way to change the font size(s) of everything in my app, so that I can have it like an accessibility feature. So I can set my font to be small medium and large. I've been testing this in a separate app, by having a font variable that changes when I click the buttons.

I'm wondering how I refresh the view controller though, to reload the label with this new variable. I know I can do this to the label directly but I want a way of doing everything in the app.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
var fontsize = CGFloat(10)

@IBAction func small(sender: AnyObject) {
    fontsize = CGFloat(10)
}

@IBAction func big(sender: AnyObject) {
    fontsize = CGFloat(20)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    label1.font = UIFont(name: label1.font.fontName, size: fontsize)
    }


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

If you want font sizes get changed in all labels through app you will need to create a custom label and add an observer on it like following

```
class FontSizeAdjustedLabel: UILabel {

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

override init(frame: CGRect) {

    super.init(frame: frame)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "changeFontSize:", name: "FontSizeAdjusted", object: nil)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "changeFontSize:", name: "FontSizeAdjusted", object: nil)
}

func changeFontSize(notification:NSNotification){

    self.font = UIFont(name: self.font.fontName, size: notification.object as! CGFloat)
}

}
```

and then in your button actions just post a notification with a corresponding name

```
@IBAction func small(sender: AnyObject) {
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("FontSizeAdjusted", object: 10.0)
}

@IBAction func big(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("FontSizeAdjusted", object: 20.0)
}
```

Notice then in order to make this solution work you will have to change all your labels classes from UILabel to FontSizeAdjustedLabel